# Can you save an image sequence from blender's compositor without re-rendering the timeline?

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

I have an image sequence of 193 frames in the compositor. I want to save these edited images without either re-rendering the images (which took hours) or saving from the viewer node one at a time. Is there a way to do this in the compositor? Or, is there a way to view the composited image sequence in blender's VSE and save it there?
Set up below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the Compositor output into the Sequencer, you must have the Sequencer in another scene than the Compositor and add a Scene strip in it pointing to the Scene with the compositor output.

Then ensure you have these settings(in Blender 3.0+):

Properties > Post Processing > Compositor to ON

View > Scene Strip Display > Rendered

Scene Strip > Input Camera

Compositor > Use Nodes > Checked

Nb. it's very slow.

Reference: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/the-poorly-exposed-scene-strip-properties-which-results-in-bad-ux/15415

Answer (score 0):

The compositor renders what you put in your node tree.

The render layer node is responsible for rendering any 3d scene from the compositor.
**Delete any Render Layer node**, and the only render that will happen is the compositing of your image sequence.